# Strange behavior of .NET's CreateDirectory method

Tags: .net

I have the following code:

```
if (Directory.Exists("mydir"))
    Directory.Delete("mydir", true);

Directory.CreateDirectory("mydir");

...

if (!Directory.Exists("mydir"))
{
    Fail("mydir not created");
}
```

The code is to make sure mydir is new. However that code snippet intermittently fails because mydir folder is not created even I have the CreateDirectory method above. Have someone experienced similar issue?

Comment: What's the real path of mydir?  Is it a special folder?  Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: `Exists` will return `false` if any error occurs while trying to determine whether the directory exists, eg because you don't have permissions. Anyway, there's no reason to call `Exists` twise, `CreateDirectory` returns a `DirectoryInfo` object representing the new directory. Still, `Exists` will be false again if creation fails

Comment: It is a common mishap, too many anti-malware scanners, search indexers and cloud-storage utilities around to give this kind of code a chance to succeed consistently.  They open files with delete sharing so deleting seems to work fine, the file however doesn't disappear until later.  The best solution is to not do this or to rename the directory.

Comment: This is a normal folder not in any special or system folders. The last Exits call is a test only. In real Release code, it's not included. I cant understand why Directory.CreateDirectory does not throw any errors even the directory is not created intermittently. If I use DirectoryInfo.Create, then everything is good. I suspect some kind of bug in the Directory.CreateDirectory method.